# Audio is not working in Xylophone Flutter App

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, yaml, flutter-dependencies

I was building a Xylophone App using Flutter. In my app the audio is not playing after clicking on buttons. How should I fix this problem?
I have attached the main.dart code and pubsec.yaml code below for reference.
Kindly suggest me what should I do to fix this problem. I am using Android Studio as editor.
Expected Result: When we click any button on the app it should play an audio.
The graphics are working fine but audio is not playing when I click on any button of Xylophone in my app.

main.dart code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

void main() => runApp(XylophoneApp());

class XylophoneApp extends StatelessWidget {
  void playSound(int soundNumber) {
    final player = AudioCache();
    player.play('note$soundNumber.wav');
  }

  Expanded buildKey({Color color, int soundNumber}) {
    return Expanded(
      child: FlatButton(
        color: color,
        onPressed: () {
          playSound(soundNumber);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              buildKey(color: Colors.red, soundNumber: 1),
              buildKey(color: Colors.orange, soundNumber: 2),
              buildKey(color: Colors.yellow, soundNumber: 3),
              buildKey(color: Colors.green, soundNumber: 4),
              buildKey(color: Colors.teal, soundNumber: 5),
              buildKey(color: Colors.blue, soundNumber: 6),
              buildKey(color: Colors.purple, soundNumber: 7),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

pubsec.yaml code

```
name: xylophone
description: A new Flutter application.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  audioplayers: ^0.20.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/note1.wav
    - assets/note2.wav
    - assets/note3.wav
    - assets/note4.wav
    - assets/note5.wav
    - assets/note6.wav
    - assets/note7.wav
```

Answer (score 0):

IT WORKS!!!
After doing a bit of research, I came across an answer on Github.
So to fix this issue you need to change **ext.kotlin_version** in **build.gradle**.
To change that you need to right click on android folder from your project tree > click on Flutter > click on Open Android module in Android Studio

Now you can open it in the same window or in a new one

1. > click on Gradle Scripts from project tree
2. > open build.gradle (the first file)
3. > finally change the ext.kotlin_version parameter to the latest version in my case 1.5.30 and sync gradle project and you will begood to go.